# Where to put cache clearing code

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

I'm putting together a ZF based CMS at the moment, and am currently caching my `Zend_Navigation` object, as well as the html rendered by `renderMenu()`.  So at the moment, whenever the menu changes, I have to call the following lines in the relevant action:

```
        $cache = Zend_Registry::get("cache");
        $cache->remove("menu");
        $frontcache = Zend_Registry::get("frontcache");
        $frontcache->remove("menuhtml");
```

I have a siteController to handle changes to the menu structure, and a pageController to handle add/edit/delete of individual pages, so the code is used in actions in both of these controllers.

I would obviously like to put this code in a single method I can call, but where would be the most appropriate place?  An action helper?  A parent class for siteController & pageController?  Should I combine the controllers?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at using an Action Helper ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html )? This will give you a place that's independent of your controllers that each controller will still be able to call.

Comment: Yes, having looked around and read a bit more, in particular [this](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3350), I think an Action Helper is the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about a service? `Application_Service_Navigation` (or whatever `appnamespace` you are using) stored in `application/services/Navigation.php`, implementing an interface representing the CRUD operations in those two CMS controllers. Then internally, these methods can use the cache as you have described. Controllers call the service methods and are unaware of the cache operations.

Comment: Would a service be better than an action helper in any way?